# Flutter Google Map works on debug but does not work if I download from Play Store

Tags: flutter, google-maps

Google map on Flutter debug works fine, however, when I upload it to Play Store, it does not work anymore. I feel like there is something to do with the API Key settings. However, I am wondering what I have to change.

My key is restricted on Android apps with the package name and SHA-1 key. And, I think this is the problem?

How can I change the setting to make this work from Google Play Store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app targets Android 12 or higher and contains `activities`, `services`, or `broadcast receivers` that use `intent filters`, you must explicitly declare the `android:exported` attribute for these app components.

more info [click here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported)

Comment: I had to add one more SHA1 from the upload key! But thank you for your answer mate.